# optical aspect ratio not consistent with supportedPictureSizes

Tags: android-camera, pixel, android-camera2, aspect-ratio

I have discovered that certain tablets (e.g. Samsung SM-T210 - Galaxy Tab 3) have equal horizontal and vertical angles of view (implying aspect ratio = 1), while NONE of their camera1.parameters supported picture sizes have an aspect ratio of 1 (closest being 1.33). What's going on? Are pixel pitches different in the x and y directions? Is come kind of cropping always applied?

I am testing an augmented reality app, and I need to have a very clear understanding of how an optical point maps onto the sensor and then onto the screen or image.

On devices supporting Camera2, one can discover the actual physical sensor size, the pixel sensor size, and the pixel size actually being used, which would enable me to answer this question. But this device seems to have older hardware.

I would have thought that the largest supported pixel size would be (close to) the actual usable pixel array size.  But the largest size has Aspect ratio of 1.33, not 1.  Does this mean cropping is happening? Is there a scaler in play?  What's going on??

Comment: How do you know that angles of view are equal?

Comment: That's what's reported in the Parameters object, e.g. Camera.Parameters#getHorizontalViewAngle().  getHorizontalViewAngle() and getVerticalViewAngle() values are the same.

Comment: I would not trust these values retrieved from getParameters(), unless an independent measurement confirms them.

Comment: Which values *would* you trust?

Comment: You can take some pictures in controlled environment, and measure the view angles.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57115610/192373