# Camera 2 CameraCharacteristics seem to show incorrect data

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have downloaded and changed Google's [Camera 2 Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) example. My changes add iterating through camera devices and showing some of their characteristics. I created this function:

```
private void printCameraCharacteristics() {
    Log.d(TAG, "printCameraCharacteristics");
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "------------------------------ "+ cameraId +" ----------------------------------");
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                    = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

            // Examine the LENS_FACING characteristic
            Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
            if(facing == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Facing: NULL");
            }
            else if(facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK){
                Log.d(TAG, "Facing: BACK");
            } else if(facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT){
                Log.d(TAG, "Facing: FRONT");
            } else if(facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL){
                Log.d(TAG, "Facing: EXTERNAL");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Facing: UNKNOWN");
            }

            // Check if the flash is supported.
            Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
            if(available == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Flash unknown");
            }
            else if(available){
                Log.d(TAG, "Flash supported");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Flash unsupported");
            }

            // Check how much the zoom is supported
            Float zoom = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM);
            Log.d(TAG, "Max supported digital zoom: " + zoom);

            // Write all the available focal lengths
            float[] focalLengths = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS);
            Log.d(TAG, "Available focal lengths: " + Arrays.toString(focalLengths));

            // Check the distortion
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                float[] lensDistortionCoefficients = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_RADIAL_DISTORTION);
                Log.d(TAG, "Lens distortion coefficients : " + Arrays.toString(lensDistortionCoefficients));
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "----------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CameraAccessException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And I just added it to the example by changing `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    printCameraCharacteristics();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_basic, container, false);
}
```

And I got the following output for Huawei P30 Pro:

```
D/Camera2BasicFragment: ------------------------------ 0 ----------------------------------
D/Camera2BasicFragment: Facing: BACK
    Flash supported
    Max supported digital zoom: 10.0
D/Camera2BasicFragment: Available focal lengths: [5.56]
    Lens distortion coefficients : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]        
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------ 1 ----------------------------------
    Facing: FRONT
    Flash unsupported
    Max supported digital zoom: 6.0
    Available focal lengths: [3.36]
    Lens distortion coefficients : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]        
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
D/Camera2BasicFragment: ------------------------------ 2 ----------------------------------
    Facing: BACK
    Flash unsupported
    Max supported digital zoom: 10.0
    Available focal lengths: [5.56]
    Lens distortion coefficients : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]    
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------ 3 ----------------------------------
D/Camera2BasicFragment: Facing: BACK
    Flash unsupported
    Max supported digital zoom: 10.0
    Available focal lengths: [2.35]
    Lens distortion coefficients : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]       
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------ 4 ----------------------------------
    Facing: BACK
    Flash unsupported
    Max supported digital zoom: 10.0
    Available focal lengths: [14.46]
D/Camera2BasicFragment: Lens distortion coefficients : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]        
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, some of the output seems inconsistent. P30 Pro has one camera with 5x zoom and [the documentation says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS) that the get for the `LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS` parameter will return an array longer than 1 for a camera that supports optical zoom. Huawei P30 Pro also has an ultrawide camera and, from my understanding, the `LENS_RADIAL_DISTORTION` should return some other parameters than `0`.

I have tested this example with Xiaomi Mi 9, which has 4 cameras, and I only get 2.

My question is: what is going on here? Why am I getting all this data that is inconsistent with what should be shown? Is my understanding of what should be shown, and thus my example, wrong?

Comment: As for mi 9, they don't report about physical lenses, only the logical ones. It's true that Android Pie does support queries for physical sub-lenses of logical multi-lense cameras, but Xiaomi apparently have chosen to reuse an older HAL.

Comment: @Alex Do you believe there is a chance of them pushing a new HAL with an update?

Comment: I believe that if there is a strong social push for that, they could. But Xiaomi is not famous for frequent OTA updates. More likely to see such new features in Mi 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This observation is very sad and very true. Wrong reporting has haunted Android cameras since day one. The multiple manufacturers have not enough incentive to provide accurate values for multiple cameras they install on their multiple devices.

They would only make sure that their preinstalled camera app works decently, and test few heavyweight 3rd party apps like Instagram and Snapchat. Parameters that are not used by these apps may have arbitrary values.

We end up keeping a list of tweaks, based on device model and build number. Sometimes similar devices have similar bugs, sometimes they don't. Some bugs are fixed with OTA updates, other bugs are introduced with such updates. Most of these tweaks can be pushed to the devices without forcing app upgrade from PlayStore.

Sorry for not having a magic pill for this common trouble.

Comment: Okay, this sounds very bad. Any idea on how I would use optical zoom or ultrawide mode in my app, then?

Comment: @AlexCohn Can you share the list of tweaks you mentioned here?

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal unfortunately, this list is not public. Also, it only covers the (very few) characteristics that our app was concerned with.

Comment: sad, huawei mate30 pro have quit something about camera2 apis, breaks my weekend

Comment: Can confirm this. We just started developing on a Huawei P40 Pro and the camera API is beyond broken. Best try to avoid Camera2 and switch to Android.Camera. It's still not perfect but way better.