# Camera calibration Android without using OpenCV

Tags: android, android-camera2, arcore, camera-calibration

I am trying to get the Camera calibration parameters ( intrinsic & extrinsic) from the Camera2 API. From API level 23, it seems that all the parameters are available as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics).

I tried getting the [LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION) & [LENS_POSE_ROTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_POSE_ROTATION) but all values are null. Please see my below implementation.

```
 CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(String.valueOf(CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_BACK));
 float[] intrinsics = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION);
 float[] pose = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_POSE_ROTATION);
```

I did my research, It seems that [ARCoreFragment](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/ArFragment), is also using Camera2 API and the same parameters for getting the rotation and intrinsics. I wanted to know is there a way I could get these parameters without using ARCore?

Comment: 1) What device are you testing on? 2) I found this [post](https://medium.com/6d-ai/how-is-arcore-better-than-arkit-5223e6b3e79d) informative regarding 6DOF calibration and why ARCore has a limited set of supported devices.

Comment: I am actually testing it on Ref Camera running android. Don't want the dependency of ARCore.

Comment: Exactly, I went through the post about 6DOF but that has nothing to do with calibration. The issue here is that there seems to be some disconnect between there API's. These 2 documentation talk about the same parameters one supports ARCore and one doesn't and the ARCore documentation seems to give the results,

Comment: Not sure what device you are referring to, note that the documentation you link to list both parameters as **OPTIONAL** so it would be up to the manufacturer to populate. If its a reference device for AOSP/custom hardware, you should reach out to the manufacturer regarding Camera2 HAL drivers.

Comment: True, it depends on Camera2 HAL drivers explicitly but these characteristics parameters are giving null values for most of the devices even Google Pixel.

Comment: Even if some characteristics are not declared OPTIONAL, they must be taken with a grain of salt, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/56918010/192373.

Comment: I totally agree with your point of these values entirely depending on the camera manufacturers and there seems to be a disconnect with what the values are in a real environment, but it seems that ARCore does manage to go around this hurdle. It seems that the fall back for me all those developers not using ARCore is to use Open CV for manual camera calibration.

Comment: hi, did you find any solution to get intrinsic camera calibration parameters in android???

Comment: @smoothumut these parameters are very subjective based on the device you are trying to test on as I was testing them on Camera these parameters were not available due to hardware capabilities of camera don't support   spatial sensors.

Android phones above api level 23 should be good to support these parametes.